# EF Include on ICollection<T>

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using EF Code-First, version 6.0.
My data model:

```
    public class City
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Person> Inhabitants { get; set; }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        //...
        public SocialID IDRecord;
    }

    public class SocialID
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        //...
    }
```

Now, I can fetch the people of a certain city using .Include.
But suppose I fetch the city first, in some part of the program, and pass it along to a different module later.

```
void DoSomething(City city)
{
foreach (var person in city.Inhabitants)
{
     // how to load person.IDRecord at this time?
}
}
```

Is there any way to fetch person.IDRecord at this time, without having access to the DBContext?

Comment: you cannot without include the IDRecord entity, or your context is enabling the Lazy loading. Are you in a disconnected mode?

Comment: So is it possible to enable lazy loading for person.IDRecord? Lazy loading is enabled in my configuration and I made the IDRecord property virtual, but it is not lazy-loaded.